# Spark: Window and UDAF for Kalman filter

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, kalman-filter

In [High Performance Spark: Best Practices for Scaling and Optimizing Apache  Spark](https://books.google.fr/books?id=90glDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA259&lpg=PA259&dq=window+kalman+sprk&source=bl&ots=Fz7NK-Sky9&sig=VxLMvS7BglgE5zu2wzTJw7VCp04&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjH39ao-ajfAhVFCuwKHb1aC2sQ6AEwBnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=window%20kalman%20sprk&f=false) by Holden Karau and  Rachel Warren it is said (pp.259):

> Window operations allow you to compute your data over the last K batches of data, which can be very handy for things like moving averages or Kalman filters

As a reminder, a Kalman is a sequential processing, used to filter a set of data based on previous data.
After looking what at the behavior of UDAFs, it doesn't seem to be adapted as there is no notion of ordering (the merge method merges the results with no order).

So if UDAF are not adapted to kalman and windowing, how can a Kalman filter be computed within a window?
Is there any example of such use of windowing?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the quote talks specifically about *Window operations* so your assumptions that

> the merge method merges the results with no order

doesn't necessarily hold. If window function is applied with `ORDER BY` clause, i.e.

```sql
F(...) OVER (ORDER BY ... [<ROW or RANGE clause>])
```

or

```sql
F(...) OVER (PARTITION BY ... [<ROW or RANGE clause>])
```

explicit order is defined by the context of the expression and merge is invoked in a well defined manner.

As a side effect aggregate function used with `OVER` is sequential (globally in the former case, by partition in the latter case) so `merge` is never invoked.